# How to install "Minimal Ubuntu" onto virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, virtualbox

This week Canonical [released](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/07/09/minimal-ubuntu-released) optimised variant of Ubuntu server distribution called **Minimal Ubuntu**. But there are no `.iso` files in provided images there.

Is it possibile to install this distribution on classic virtual machine like Virtual Box of VmWare workstation?

Comment: Like This? https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-lts-minimal-server/ You can install normaly and make Template on WMWARE, later deploy

Comment: Your answer is something totally different. I'm asking if there is a way to install these so-called "ubuntu cloud images" into virtual-machine. These images are raw (binary) images of harddrive.

Comment: U can make script to convert to vdi like:
https://gist.github.com/smoser/6066204

Comment: So just to clarify, are you asking how to convert a .img file like they provide to a .iso (which would not work as the .img appears to be a disk image and not an installation file) or are you asking if you can make an installation image from a disk image?

Comment: @cteneyck converting to ISO will probably won't work here. It is not an installation image. I probably misspelled the title - I want to boot these images in virtual machine and then work with it as regular Ubuntu linux VM.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution? Most of tutorials confuse Ubuntu Server (~600MB) with Ubuntu Minimal (~300MB). There is only IMG file left with Jammy release: http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/jammy/release/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late, but I found your question today. I published a gist recently that hopefully solves your problem.

Abstract:

"The mini.iso for the Ubuntu distribution is legacy since version 20.04LTS (Focal Fossa). This is a bad news for those (like me) that formerly used this distribution to produce lightweight virtual machines for development, teaching, testing, etc. A distribution of the mini.iso for Ubuntu 20.04 is indeed still available here, but there is no guarantee that its availability will continue after Focal Fossa. So I decided to find a way to do without the mini.iso, and I wrote this script that takes to the ''tasksel'' step starting from a cloud image in the ubuntu repository. Surprise, it is faster than the procedure based on the mini.iso."

Link: https://gist.github.com/AugustoCiuffoletti/e0af693878e8fa9ab5b6e8d761eb9eec

Answer (score 0):

Only disk images are released, so not as an iso.  You could convert the disk images provided, probably with `qemu-image convert`.  Edit:  and boot the resulting image directly, as a disk.

In my opinion, if you wish for interactive use, you will have a better experience to using the server iso.  It has editors and manuals and other nice to haves beyond just the bare minimum for ssh access. And still is a relatively small size to install, secure, and maintain.

Comment: as I mentioned in other answer, I know these are a disk boot images. My intention is to have smallest Ubuntu server machine possible. With deafult ISO files I get machine that is around 1.2GB after clean installation.
Prospect of having ubuntu server which is only around 200MB is what I'm wanting to achieve.

Comment: If it wasn't obvious, boot the converted disk image of minimal. Edited to mention that.     The general installer .iso is not going to produce an install this small, otherwise it would be an option.

Comment: I tried converting Ubuntu Minimal 22 LTS IMG to VDI, but it still does not boot in VirtualBox. http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/jammy/release/